# Visualizing multiple searches in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

So I have a single index in elasticsearch I want to visualize with Kibana. I want to visualize the field `temperature` but I want to separate based on the value in `sensor_name`. Is there any way to craft a search query that would let me do that or is that simply not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the y-axis to use the `temperature` field, perhaps with min/max/avg, etc.

You'll typically set the x-axis to a date histogram, to show the change in values over time.

Now, to group these values by `sensor_name`, you'll want an aggregation, which is available in kibana4 just under the x-axis definition.  Select 'terms' and the `sensor_name` field.  That should do it!